# NSdata length crash on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate

While running this code:

```
NSData *archivedSavedData = [[NSData alloc] init];    
archivedSavedData = [defaults objectForKey:@"listOfAccessNumbers"];
NSLog(@"archivedSavedData length is %d", [archivedSavedData length] );
```

I am getting this crash error (last line) only when running on a device that is connected:

> [__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2398a0
>   2012-03-13 20:25:33.088[7301:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2398a0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x34dbc88f 0x361e3259 0x34dbfa9b 0x34dbe915 0x34d19650 0xccb1b 0x31e13e33 0x31e38629 0x31dfcd7d 0x31ebf4dd 0x31e0555d 0x31e05579 0x31e0540b 0x31e053e7 0xcfedf 0x31e12e53 0x31e0c985 0x31ddac6b 0x31dda70f 0x31dda0e3 0x3600f22b 0x34d90523 0x34d904c5 0x34d8f313 0x34d124a5 0x34d1236d 0x31e0ba13 0x31e08e7d 0xcfd39 0xcbe28)
>   terminate called throwing an exception

This doesn't happen when running on the simulator or directly on the device with a distribution profile (through testflight for example).

Does anyone know how such a behavior could happen only in this case?

Thanks.

UPDATE: when trying to replace length with count I get this complication error: "No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'count'"

UPDATE2: I understand that it should be an NSArray rather than an NSData, but my problem is that I did store archived NSData cause my array consists of custom objects, so I had to archived this data into NSData format when saving in NSUserDefault. How else should I approach that otherwise?

Thats how I store the data:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
   [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"listOfAccessNumbers"];
```

array is an array of custom objects of the form of:

```
@interface NumberDataObj : NSObject {

    NSString *inputName;
    NSString *inputNum;

}
```

Comment: 1. yes, ARC is enabled, and 2. i could do this in one line, but i still need to declare it...no?

Comment: The problem is you apparently have the variable declared as NSData, but the pointer stored in the variable is an NSArray.  This could be just a "dumb" mistake -- assigning an NSArray to the variable -- or it could be some sort of storage management problem (and they don't go away with ARC, they just get different).

Comment: We may need to see where you serialize your objects in order to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Could the issue, then, be that `NumberDataObj` doesn't implement the `NSCoding` protocol?

Comment: it does actually...i think sch is on the solution.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you've bitten off more than you can chew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says:

```
-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

That means that `archivedSavedData` is an array and that it doesn't (obviously) respond to `length` so you should declare `archivedSavedData` as an array and use `count` instead.

```
NSArray *archivedSavedData = [defaults objectForKey:@"listOfAccessNumbers"];
NSLog(@"archivedSavedData length is %d", [archivedSavedData count]);
```

Now, as to why this doesn't happen when running on the simulator, my guess is that your test scenarios don't make this part of the code get called.

**EDIT**

If you want to retrieve the data as `NSData` then use the method `dataForKey:`

```
NSData *archivedSavedData = [defaults dataForKey:@"listOfAccessNumbers"];
NSLog(@"archivedSavedData length is %d", [archivedSavedData length]);
```

---

The documentation says for `dataForKey`:

> **Return Value**
>   The data object associated with the specified key, or nil if the key does not exist or its value is not an NSData object.

and for `arrayForkey`:

> **Return Value**
>   The array associated with the specified key, or nil if the key does not exist or its value is not an NSArray object.

So aways use the appropriate method when you know the type of the data to avoid problems like this.

Comment: I think you are on something...checking now.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems as the code is written:

1) You allocate a variable called archivedSavedData that you reassign on the following line without releasing.  This is okay if you are working with ARC, but the first line would then be unnecessary.

2) The second problem is that the object corresponding to the key @"listOfAccessNumbers" stored in your defaults object is of type NSArray.  NSArray responds to the selector count, not length.  Maybe you should look more closely at this object and recode accordingly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am working with ARC, and the reason why I use NSData is because this is an array of custom objects, so when I stored them I used archiving...not sure how else to do that...

Answer (score 2):

It's because `[defaults objectForKey:@"listOfAccessNumbers"]` returns an `NSArray`, not an `NSData` object.